# Stop OnCtlColor() changing combobox's (edit control)'s "text color" 

Tags: mfc, combobox

The MFC combobox is really a wierd design.

I use "drop list" type combo box.

```
HBRUSH CValueInputDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)  
{
    HBRUSH hBrush = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC || nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT)
    {
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));  
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);  
        hBrush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }    
    return hBrush;
}
```

what I do is having all my CStatic and CEdit color WHITE.

but i discover that I also change the combobox's edit to white.

that is what I don't want.

that is what I don't want. and I can't stop it from

```
pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_COMBO
```

it is so unfriendly. this combo box.

Comment: Don't blame MFC. This is how the underlying Windows control is built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Edit box is a child of the combo box. Try this:

`pWnd->GetParent()->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_COMBO`

Comment: This is the right answer +1, and to further clarify you'll need `if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC || (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT && pWnd->GetParent()->GetDlgCtrlID() != IDC_COMBO))` ...